# How to add return form in magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2.2, orders, third-party-module, rma

How to add return form in my Magento 2.3. I added **"MAGEWORX"** for shipping service ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on community edition Return management is not part of it

You would have create a RMA module or [Buy some existing modules](https://www.mageplaza.com/review/rma/)

If you are on Enterprise Edition

You can enable it with following steps

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.
2. In the panel on the left, under Sales, choose Sales.
3. Expand the RMA Settings section. Then, do the following:
   RMA Settings
    a. Set Enable RMA on Storefront to “Yes.”

[Reference 1](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/rma-configure.html) [Reference 2](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/widget-orders-returns.html)

Comment: thanks for your instruction. In my admin panel there is no " RMA Settings" in Stores->Configuration->Sales

Comment: Then you are on community edition ,  you have to create RMA module or buy existing module

Comment: i used [link] https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/widget-orders-returns.html for  sample page, but order retrun form was only showing in sigout customer